# Android app unable to start activity ComponentInfo after running on Android Studio (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to run an application on my phone using the "Run 'app'" function on Android Studio. The app crashes on startup and refuses to work.

I've succeded in running the app on my phone once, but it was much earlier than when this problem existed. It happened probably at an attempted fix at a compiling error, which indeed fixed it, but brings this other problem. No other question has helped me since none of them used kotlin, and I couldn't pinpoint the exact error I may have done.

Here is the [logcat](http://txt.do/1dk3b). (text was exceeding the 30000 character limit)

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.example.testapp">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,android:appComponentFactory"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the `MainActivity.kt`:

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textMessage: TextView
    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_home)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        textMessage = findViewById(R.id.message)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }}
}
```

Lastly, the `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#585858"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="184dp" app:srcCompat="@mipmap/image1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:contentDescription="Image 1"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="36dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="151dp"
            android:layout_height="153dp" app:srcCompat="@mipmap/image2"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If any more code is needed, I'll be sharing.

Normally, as in my first attempt way back at when I started development, the app would run normally, and wouldn't crash. Now, the app crashes instantly after being run, no matter if it's run by Android Studio or by installing an apk in the target device.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting while starting activity.

Comment: And first of all in kotlin we don't need to do findViewByID

Comment: I think see your build gradle file and check log cat.Invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the multidex support in your `app/build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing as you said, but it didn't work.
My activity_main.xml seems to be having a lot of problems as well, maybe that has something to do with this?

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using Clean Project, Invalidate Caches and Restart and Rebuild Project. None of them seemed to work.

Comment: Please post your layout.

Comment: Added to main post.

Answer (score 0):

in your onNavigationItemSelectedListener,you had not init TextView textMessage.

```
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{ item->
when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_home)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                textMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
}
```